# How to display compare products,recently viewed/compared products in category and product page only?

Tags: magento

I want to display "compare products,recently viewed/compared products blocks" only in category and product page.And hide at all other places in modern theme.
How can i do this? Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Disclaimer: This is not intended to be a lesson on layouts, please see a tutorial for that - there are lots around, and lots of questions on here. One from the Magento site is found at http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts

You need to edit the layout files here. Let's take one of your requests as an example; Compare products:

In the `catalog.xml` file, you can see something like this at the top:

```
<default>
...
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
...
```

Now this is telling it to show in all pages (that don't explicitly remove it, assuming they have a `right` block), in the right column.

It sounds like you want it on these pages, but not others, so lets move it from here and move it into the category pages and product pages.

In this document, you will also see tags such as:

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
```

If we add the above inside that, putting the following in the `<reference name="right">` tag, or left if you prefer, creating it if it isn't there already:

```
<block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
```

And similarly for the product view

```
 <catalog_product_view translate="label">
```

Now, you may find it still appears in other pages, such as the `My Account` page. The layout for this is in `customer.xml` where the following can be found:

```
<customer_account translate="label">
...
    <reference name="left">
    ...
        <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
...
```

the `<block type...` tag mentioned above should be removed from here.

This has hopefully given you an idea of how what you want to do is achieved.